# Linked List Deletion

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

**What's wrong in the below delete method logic? Why am I not getting correct output After Deletion.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//Node Class

class Node1 {

 int data;

 Node1 Next;

 Node1(int data) {

  this.data = data;

  Next = null;

 }

}

//Main Class

public class LinkedListInsert {

 //Inserting node in LinkedList

 public static Node1 insert(Node1 head, int data) {

  Node1 p = new Node1(data);

  if (head == null)

   head = p;

  else {

   Node1 start = head;

   while (start.Next != null)

    start = start.Next;

   start.Next = p;

  }

  return head;

 }

 //Deleting node from LinkedList

 public static Node1 delete(Node1 head, int d) {

  Node1 start = head;

  while (start.data != d) {

   start = start.Next;

  }

  while (start.Next != null) {

   start.data = start.Next.data;

   start = start.Next;

  }

  start = null;

  return head;

 }

 //Displaying Linked List

 public static void display(Node1 head) {

  Node1 start = head;

  while (start != null) {

   System.out.print(start.data + " ");

   start = start.Next;

  }

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  int n;

  Node1 head = null;

  System.out.println("Enter the numbers of node to be inserted");

  n = sc.nextInt();

  while (n--> 0) {

   System.out.println("enter node");

   head = insert(head, sc.nextInt());

  }

  System.out.println("Before Deletion");

  display(head);

  delete(head, 3);//I have hard coded the deleting node as 3

  System.out.println();

  System.out.println("After Deletion");

  display(head);

 }

}
```

**Input:** 6 2 3 1 8

Node to be deleted: 3

**Output:**

Before Deletion

6 2 3 1 8

After Deletion

6 2 1 8 8

As you can see node 3 is deleted from the list but 8 is coming for 2 times. 
**//I have hard coded the deleting node as 3**

Comment: Please edit your question to format the code properly - use the preview to make sure your question looks appropriate *before* posting. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for Markdown details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is a bug in delete(), you didn't delete any node actually, you only changed the value of the node you want to delete and all nodes' value to next node's. Here is a modified code, you can use delete2() to test:

```
    //Deleting node from LinkedList

public static Node1 delete2(Node1 head, int d) {
    if (head.data == d) {
        // Delete head node
        return head.Next;
    }
    Node1 start = head;

    while (start.Next != null) {
        if (start.Next.data == d) {
            // Delete the next node
            start.Next = start.Next.Next;
            break;
        }
        start = start.Next;
    }
    return head;
}

public static Node1 delete(Node1 head, int d) {

    Node1 start = head;

    while (start.data != d) {

        start = start.Next;

    }

    while (start.Next != null) {

        start.data = start.Next.data;

        start = start.Next;

    }

    start = null;

    return head;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use the below code display the values of linked list.

```
public void display(){
        LinkedNode currNode =head;
        while(true){
            if(currNode == null){
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Iterating a LinkedList=-=-=-=>"+currNode.val);
            currNode = currNode.nxt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: still showing the same output with this display() logic also.

Answer (score 0):

Please format the source code properly.

I was just going through the code you have provided. Here it looks like before deletion you are inserting node first and then you are deleting. Definitely the list also will show you what you have added through the insertion when it asks "enter node".

Please verify the same.

I just tried the same. Once I give input of 
6 2 3 1 8

Then it asks to enter node and I added 9
Again I added 0

Then I got the below output:

Before Deletion
2 3 1 8 9 0 
After Deletion
2 1 8 9 0 0

Hence it deleted 6 from LinkedList.

Comment: the actual input is  :
Enter the numbers of node to be inserted
5
enter node
6
enter node
2
enter node
3
enter node
1
enter node
8
Before Deletion
6 2 3 1 8 
After Deletion
6 2 1 8 8

The 1st integer is taken as the size of linked list